# insert UIPicker selected value into UITextField

Tags: ios, tags, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am trying to figure out how to pass a selected `UIPicker` value into a `UITextField`. I have created the picker and several `UItextFields` with `.tag` to identity which `UITextField` to put the value into, however i Just dont know how to do it.

This is the method I am using when the `UIPickerView` is tapped

```
// Do something with the selected row.
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [dataArray objectAtIndex: row]);

    NSString *temp = [dataArray objectAtIndex:row]; // this contains the selected value from UIPickerView
    NSLog(@"%@", temp);

//    if (cutField.tag == 0) { // trying to pass the string to the correct UItextfield... or any UItextfield for that matter
        cutField.text = temp;
//    }

}
```

The method above is actioned but there is never a value set in the cutField. I don't know how to identify which one should be updated as I don't know how to access the tag value.

This is how I assign the tag value of the `UITextField`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cutCount; i++) 
{
      //first one
      cutField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((positions*i)-(20/2)+(positions/2)), 25, 20, 20)];
      cutField.inputView = pickerView;
      cutField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
      cutField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
      cutField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
      [view addSubview:cutField];

      cutField.tag = tagNumber;
      tagNumber ++;

      [columnArrayOfTextFields addObject:cutField]; // array of textfields
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the superview that contains all those 'cutFields'. I've called it `containerView` in the example below. Also, your example is using '0' as the tag, so I used that below too. Although I would have assumed you would be using a variable for that too.

Then use:

```
((UITextField *)[self.containerView viewWithTag:0]).text = temp;
```

Or spread out over multiple lines:

```
UITextField* textField = (UITextField*) [self.containerView viewWithTag:0];
textField.text = temp;
```

Comment: I am getting an error, expected identifier on the last square bracket.

Comment: this code contains and error.. trying to figure it out myself but hard to find any refrences online

Comment: @HurkNburkS sorry, I didn't actually check the code if it compiled, I just had the casting scoping brackets wrong. `viewWithTag` only returns the base class `UIView` so you have to cast before accessing the `text` property.

Comment: okay this works at inputting text into a UItextfield but for some reason its not inputting the text into the textfield i define using the .tag.

Answer (score 0):

you have just instantiation one `UITextField` so the `cutField.tag` is `cutCount-1` you can try like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cutCount; i++) {
            //first one
            UITextField *cutField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((positions*i)-(20/2)+(positions/2)), 25, 20, 20)];
            cutField.inputView = pickerView;
            cutField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
            cutField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
            cutField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [view addSubview:cutField];

            cutField.tag = tagNumber;
            tagNumber ++;



            [columnArrayOfTextFields addObject:cutField]; // array of textfields
        }
```